# JsTree, JsTreeGrid - Get parent node when making grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jstree

I use JsTree with JsTreeGrid plugin. https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid

I want to get parent node's Quantity to multiply it with current node's Quantity to obtain Extended quantity.

See code:

```
grid: {
    columns: [
        {header: "Title", value: function(node){return(node.text);}},
        {width: 150, header: "Quantity", value: function(node){return(node.data.quantity);}},
        {width: 150, header: "Extended Quantity", 
                value: function(node) {
                    return(get_parent(node).quantity*node.quantity);
                }}
    ]
}
```

It gives me: Uncaught ReferenceError: get_parent is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the jstree instance to get the data for the parent node. The grid documentation does not seem to have a get_parent method. Here's one way to do the same by the getting the jstree instance & the parent node from that instance.

```
var oTree = $('#jstree_demo_div');
oTree.jstree({
    "core": {
        //...
        //...
        'data': data
    },
    grid: {
        columns: [{ header: "Title", value: function (node) { return (node.text); } },
        { width: 150, header: "Quantity", value: function (node) { return (node.data.quantity); } },
        {
            width: 150, header: "Extended Quantity",
            value: function (node) {
                var parent = oTree.jstree(true).get_node(node.parent);
                if(parent.hasOwnProperty('data')){ //Root node has no data
                    return (parent.data.quantity * node.data.quantity);
                }
                return(node.data.quantity);
            }
        }]
    },
    "plugins": ["grid"]
});
```